# Pass function param to ngSweetAlert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

Help me find an approach for this:

I am using ngSweeAlert angulajs directive for sweeAlert. So, I have a simple code:

```
function test() {
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  },
  function(isConfirm){
    if(isConfirm) alert("foobar")
    else alert("notfoobar")
  }); 
}
```

I want pass a function for test function:

```
function myFunction( isConfirm ) {
     if(isConfirm) alert("foobar")
     else alert("notfoobar")
}
```

Where test function works this way:

```
function test(callBack ) {
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      },
      callback
      ); 
    }
```

My problem is myFunction function is :

```
 function myFunction( isConfirm, param1, param2 ) {
         if(isConfirm) alert("foobar"+param1);
         else alert("notfoobar"+param2);
    }
```

Then, the first param only occurs when a press ok or cancel buttons. I call test function

```
test( function(){ return myFunction(undefined,'beautiful','uggly') } )
```

My question is: How I can do to take isConfirm 'true' or 'false' for sweetAlert for user interaction when I wave a function with another two params param1 and param2 after isConfirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myFunction( param1,param2 ) {  
    test ( 
      function( isConfirm ) {
        if(isConfirm) return "foo"+param1;
        else return "bar"+param2;
       });  
   );
};
```